# Is there a way to update skill training without the EVE client?

Tags: eve-online

I'm not going to be home for the next two weeks, so I was wondering if there's any way to change the skill training of your pilot in EVE online without actually having the client. I look at EVE gate and several of the iPhone clients, but didn't see anything that would actually let you change the skill being trained. Thanks!

Answer (score 15, accepted):

No. There is no way to do this. It is a very requested feature.

The alternative is to queue up a long skill, such as Battlecruiser 5.

In case you did not know, sometime in 2013, the Destroyer and Battlecruiser skills will be split into racial skills. So if you have all the cruisers at 3 (or higher) and BC at 5, you will end up with all 4 racial battlecruiser skills at 5.

Answer (score 4):

At this time, no you cannot. The current EVE API system is a read only system that receives XML responses from EVE servers.

However there is a new API system called CREST that is set to release beta early next year that will allow write commands to be given to the EVE system, and one thing this COULD provide is the ability to update Skills.

As of right now they have stated that they intend of having it allow you to update contacts/chat with your corporation, however other features can be added once the fiddly bits are worked out.

[Link](http://wiki.eveonline.com/en/wiki/CREST_Documentation)

Answer (score 2):

No, not yet. [Today's dev blog](http://community.eveonline.com/devblog.asp?a=blog&nbid=73971) (29th December 2012) gives the first details of the [CREST API for EVE Online and Dust 514](http://wiki.eveonline.com/en/wiki/CREST_Documentation) which may eventually allow you to update skill training without entering the game client.

So keep your fingers crossed. I will update this answer with more details as they come.

Comment: Baaaad answer! "may eventually"... As long as you doesn't know for sure, you should not post as an answer, but as a comment...

Comment: It's still an answer, just as 'no' is an answer, and adding links to the information doesn't work well in comments

Comment: Also, its a "May eventually" since I am about 99.9999% sure he doesn't work for CCP and can't elaborate on what they'll do because of that.

Answer (score 0):

Also editing in-game settings like this may allow for out of game Macro'ing (ie in a web browser), something CCP are sure to want to avoid.